# Year, Make, Model in excel from columns

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

It has been a while since I did any Excel work and I am having a bit of trouble remembering how I did this sort of thing in the past.

I have sheet of data for motorcycle Year, Make, and Model and I would like to combine the years in a second sheet as a date range where Make and Model are the same. Basically transform the data as follows:

Source data (Sheet1):

| Year | Make | Model |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2003 | Yamaha | FZS 1 |
| 2004 | Yamaha | FZS 1 |
| 2005 | Yamaha | FZS 1 |
| 2018 | Yamaha | MT-07 |
| 2019 | Yamaha | MT-07 |
| 2020 | Yamaha | MT-07 |

Resulting data (Sheet2):

| Year Range | Make | Model |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2003-2005 | Yamaha | FZS 1 |
| 2018-2020 | Yamaha | MT-07 |

I am having trouble determining how to combine the Year column into a year range when columns B and C are equal for all the adjacent rows.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: I have added some more detail at the end of my post, perhaps that is clearer

Answer (score 0):

I used a **Table** for the motorcycle information, and **NAME**'d it: `Motorcycle` to be able to use structured references and have dynamic ranges.  *(But you can omit that and use regular references if you prefer)*

If you have Excel 2021+ or Office 365, you can use the following

- List of brand/model

  - *Entered into a single cell and the results will `SPILL`*
    `G2: =UNIQUE(Motorcycle[[Make]:[Model]])`
- Year range

  - *Entered into first cell in column and then fill/drag down as far as needed*

```
F2: =MINIFS(Motorcycle[Year],Motorcycle[Make],G2,Motorcycle[Model],H2) & " - " & MAXIFS(Motorcycle[Year],Motorcycle[Make],G2,Motorcycle[Model],H2)
```

[image]

If you have an early version, a pivot table would provide a simple solution:

- Make and Model => rows
- In values area:

  - Min of Years
  - Max of years

[image]

Answer (score -1):

You can use MINIFS and MAXIFS functions to get the result, remove Make and Model Duplicates from List:
[image]

Enter the formula:

```
=MINIFS($A$2:$A$7,$B$2:$B$7,$G$2,$C$2:$C$7,H2)&"-"&MAXIFS($A$2:$A$7,$B$2:$B$7,$G$2,$C$2:$C$7,H2)
```

[image]